# The javascript "resizeTo" function not working in Chrome and Opera

Tags: javascript, browser, resize

The resizeTo (that allows setting a new height/width value) function works great on Firefox and Internet Explorer and doesn't work at all on Chrome and Opera.

Is there another function that does the same and works on all the browsers?

Thank you,

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't another function.

The `resizeTo` method is disabled by default in several browsers, and I know that it can also be manually disabled in Firefox.

It has been widely misused, so most browser vendors feel that it should be disabled, or at least a user controllable option.

Comment: Yeah, I *thought* this was because of Chrome's and Opera's philosophy of having everything in tabs.

Comment: @jave.web: It's hard to see what's important in that answer, as about half of the text has emphasis. In what way is it that you think that the answer is not true?

Comment: @Guffa I used quotes = I literally meant "Important notes"... and the answer has headings&only important things are emphasised so it is very clear. However I am sorry, because I think I misread your answer (I did not down vote anyway) - you should definitely emphasise "**feel**" "**disabled, or at least a user controllable option.**"

Comment: For info on when it is mostly not possible to resize the window see "**Important notes:**" in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35801906/1835470

Answer (score 5):

On my way it isn't possible to resize the window when it is on top-level. (so not a pop-up)

And i think that chrome got it right by not allowing top level windows to be resized.

You can solve it:

> Resizing won't work for top-level
>   tabs, and when you open sample.htm
>   it's opened as a  top-level tab.  If
>   you instead opened it as a pop-up (for
>   example using window.open  with a
>   width and a height set), resizeTo
>   should work.

Comment: I want to underline this solution, because this is exactly how you solve this problem. If you create the window yourself, a whole suite of functions including `resizeTo`, `resizeBy`, `moveBy`, and `moveTo` (and perhaps more) become available to you in the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

Because many webmasters have made a bad use of pop-ups and resizing, some **uncompromising** browser manufacturers hopelessly just disable these functions. Other more respectful manufacturers leave them as optional.