# window.resize is not working in chrome and opera

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, opera

window.resize is not working in chrome and opera  ..how to make it work?

Comment: Hey, did you find a better answer, than please share, or accept one of these. THX

Comment: possible duplicate of [The javascript "resizeTo" function not working in Chrome and Opera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641648/the-javascript-resizeto-function-not-working-in-chrome-and-opera)

Answer (score 28):

## There is no `window.resize()`

...however...

## There are:

### [`window.resizeTo(width, height)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo)

### [`window.resizeBy(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeBy)

## Important notes:

1. You can't resize a window or tab **that wasn’t created by
   window.open**.
2. You can't resize a window or tab **when it’s in a
   window with more than one tab**.
3. Also, even if you create window by `window.open(...)` **it is not resizable by default ...see 4.**
4. To make window created by `window.open()` resizable, **you must open it with resizable feature**

**Example of how to create external window with "resizable" feature:**

```
myExternalWindow = window.open("http://myurl.domain", "myWindowName", "resizable");
myExternalWindow.resizeTo(500,500); //resize window to 500x500
myExternalWindow.resizeBy(-100,-100); //make it smaller relatively => to 400x400
```

**PS: There are also browser extensions that allow window resizing... ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh))([Mozilla Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/firesizer/))**

**PS2:** Chrome extension API - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows

Comment: I just realized where do people come from with that idea and it's because there *is* an **event** (**not** a method) called "resize" that is fired on `window` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event ) but again, that's not a method of `window`, it's just an event :)

Answer (score 4):

This is because it is not supported in Opera and Chrome...

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp

### UPDATE:

This might help you in finding something specific to what you want...

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/153185-moveto-resize-firefox

Comment: @hema: No, it simply doesn't exist there (or it exists and does nothing). Furthermore, some other browsers have the user option to disable the function, so you can't really rely on it in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: There is no public standard that applies to the Window object, but all major browsers support it.*

The `window.resizeTo()` and `window.resizeBy()` methods are supported in all major browsers, except Opera and Chrome.

refer
[Window resizeTo() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp)
[Window resizeBy() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeby.asp)

Comment: it will work in Opera and chrome in case the window is a popup

Comment: The difference is that a popup is opened by your page while the main window is opened by the user. With many tabs, why should your page have the right to change the pagesize for all tabs?

Comment: @DavidMårtensson That's a reasoning Microsoft took for IE, but they instead made the function useless only when there are other tabs open.