# Resize in firefox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Can someone tell me why resizing does not work in firefox but it works in internet explorer? I cannot figure out how to force it in all browsers. I am trying to resize the width to 800 and height to 475. Then I am trying to make it where you can not maximize the browser (disabling it). As well as removing all toolbars from showing and URL as well.

```js
function OpenWindow(url, width, height)
{
  var features = 'resizable:no;status:yes;dialogwidth:' + width + 'px;dialogheight:' + height + 'px;help:no';
     features = features + ';dialogtop:' + (window.screen.availHeight - height) /2;
  features = features + ';dialogleft:' + (window.screen.availWidth - width) /2;
  
  window.showModalDialog(url, this, features);
  
}


function Resize(width, height) 
{
 
 var availWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
 var availHeight = window.screen.availHeight;
 
 var top = (availHeight - height) / 2;
 var left = (availWidth - width) / 2;

 if (window.dialogHeight)
 {
  window.dialogHeight = height + 'px'; 
  window.dialogWidth = width + 'px'; 
  window.dialogLeft = left; 
  window.dialogTop = top;
 }
 else
 {
  var _win; 
  if(window.parent) _win = window.parent; 
  else _win = window;
  _win.resizeTo(width, height);
  _win.moveTo(left, top);
 }
}

Resize(800, 475);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any advice will help. I do not understand why things work in certain browsers and not in others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo#Notes), it's not been allowed in Firefox at all since Firefox 7. Sorry but you won't be able to resize the window in Firefox.

Comment: @Vicki Actually, [looks like it only works in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139323/window-resize-is-not-working-in-chrome-and-opera) so I would avoid it if at all possible.

Comment: lol guess that makes web apps more difficult when they want them certain sizes