# How to change the size of a window or minimize?

Tags: javascript, html

Im using this code to refresh the parent window and close the popup window..Is there any way to minimize or change the size of the popup window intead of closing it?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function refreshParent() {
  window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;

  if (window.opener.progressWindow)

 {
    window.opener.progressWindow.close()
  }
  window.close();
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641648/the-javascript-resizeto-function-not-working-in-chrome-and-opera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.resizeTo()` method. See [Example](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/resizing.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function changeScreenSize(w, h)
{
    window.resizeTo(w, h)
}
```

Comment: This isn't compatible with everything. More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641648/the-javascript-resizeto-function-not-working-in-chrome-and-opera).