# Resize the HTML5 video based on the device used to play

Tags: html, video

I am using the following code to play html5 videos:-

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/o2media.videolibrary/348.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

When i am playing this in the browser it works well but it doesnot play in the iPhone or a similar device.

How can these video be resized so that they are able to play both in the browsers and other devices?

**EDIT**

Is there any way using the javascript to resize the window on the call of a function?

Regards
Vishal

Answer (score 0):

if you want to resize the video there are two choices. The first would be to simply adjust with width/height parameters on the `<video>` element if you detect you are on an iPhone, the second would be to resize the element but also select a more appropriate bitrate video for mobile use rather than send the higher bitrate.

Using UserAgent detection (not as good) or CSS Media Queries (see this article - http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/08/combining_media.html) you can determine the size of the window you have and can alter your code accordingly.

For resizing your window ... most modern browsers disable this unless it's a window you've created yourself - see [The javascript "resizeTo" function not working in Chrome and Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641648/the-javascript-resizeto-function-not-working-in-chrome-and-opera) for more details