# Using moveTo and resizeTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning guys

I'm trying to use two jquery functions and nothing happens . Those functions are : moveTo and resizeTo .
The objective of using this is to re-open the browser when the status of my object changes to guarantee that the user will notice that on real time . To test those functions , I tried this :

```
setInterval(function loadPage() {           
    window.moveTo(0, 0);
    window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
    window.focus();
}(), 5000);
```

Doing this, nothing happens . But I tried to insert an alert before using the window.moveBy and with this the function works . I really didn't understand why and I don't wanna use alert to show a message to the user . I'll use jquery ui dialog to show this message .

Is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: Executing a function inside setTimeout makes no sense.

Comment: but I'm using setInterval

Comment: Um, the setInterval is not doing what you think it is doing. It is executing what the function returns. Add a console inside of your method and see that it will execute as soon as the code is executed, not 5 seconds later.

Comment: The setInterval is to reload the page , in this case, in every 5 secs ... This works , but the function inside doesn't

Comment: Becuase the function inside runs ONCE.

Comment: As I'm using here it reloads in every 5 secs , but forget about this ... Do you have any idea of how can I bring the window back to the user as I explained above ?

Comment: what epascarello means is: remove the () from your last line: }(), 5000); will become }, 5000); You are immediately executing the loadpage function. E.g. you don't need to specify any function name here as well.

Comment: just do this:
setInterval(function() {           
    window.moveTo(0, 0);
    window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
    window.focus();
}, 5000);

Comment: But once you get the code right, you are sort of out of luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641648/the-javascript-resizeto-function-not-working-in-chrome-and-opera Why don't you just ask permission to run the browser in full screen mode.

Comment: understood ... and about the moveTo and resizeTo functions ? I'm trying to use it at chrome , but nothing happens , only when I put an alert before those functions ... Am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Chrome has blocked resizeTo and moveTo for awhile.

Comment: hahahah Then this doesn't work at chrome at all ? Really without any luck ... But the weird thing is , by add an alert before those functions it "works" ... but only using on that way ...

Comment: Guys , thanks for the help !